# Does CodedUI Windows Store App support XAML webview automation?

Tags: webview, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently in the process of automating a XAML webview with HTML Objects. I'm having issues with codedUI's crosshair tool/"Ctrl I" finding the html elements in the wrong locations.

Is it possible to successfully automated Html objects in a Xaml webview with codedUI 2013?

Can I implement selenium with CodedUI to find these objects?

Comment: Based on this blog, it's not looking good at least for windows phone apps. I wonder if this applies to windows store apps.

"WebView control used to host HTML content in a XAML app is currently not supported."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/05/using-coded-ui-to-test-xaml-based-windows-phone-apps.aspx

Comment: using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls might be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodedUI Test Builder tool is able to identify HTML elements within a webview.

We can also use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls to indentify our own controls.

As for the wrong locations, it looks like it's an app specific issue.